# Bewildering issue - FFmpeg segment filter desyncs video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, split, synchronization, segment

I need to segment a large (72GB) Prores video file and merge the segments to get a file identical to the original.

```
./ffmpeg -i video.mov -codec copy -f segment -segment_time 300 -segment_list list.ffcat -reset_timestamps 1 -v error chunk_%d.mov
```

**Unfortunately the segments that come from running this command get out of sync after a few seconds of playback with Quicktime Player.** Interestingly, seeking, rewinding or fast forwarding appears to resync the video correctly for at least a few seconds.

The following warning appears whenever a new segment is written:

```
[segment @ 0x7f87ae001200] Opening 'chunk_0.mov' for writing
[mov @ 0x7f87ad807200] Valid timecode frame rate must be specified. Minimum value is 1
```

Yet, setting the framerate with `-r 24` doesn't help.

Some potentially relevant metadata:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'A004_04121423_C001.mov':
  Duration: 00:13:31.25, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 710117 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le(bt709, progressive), 3840x2160, 707415 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-04-12T20:23:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 14:23:16:02
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit), 2304 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-04-12T20:23:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 14:23:16:02
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-04-12T20:23:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 14:23:16:02

Output #0, segment, to 'chunk_%d.mov':
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le(bt709, progressive), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 707415 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-04-12T20:23:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 14:23:16:02
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit), 2304 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-04-12T20:23:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 14:23:16:02
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
```

I'm on OS X.

Thanks so much for your time and help on this issue! I certainly hope I'm not missing something obvious :)

---

**UPDATE (May 10):** Comparing the original video file with the segments, I've found some interesting differences. Adobe Premiere reports that t**he original video** has the following properties:

```
QuickTime Details:
Movie contains 1 video track(s), 1 audio track(s), 0 closed caption track(s), **and 1 timecode track(s).**

Video:
There are 19470 frames with a **duration of 1/24th.**

Video track 1:
Duration is **0:13:31:06**

Video data block #1:
Frame Size = 3840 x 2160
Compressor = 
**Quality = Most (-2623.00)
Temporal = Most (1.00)**

Timecode data block #1:
Start Time = 14:23:16:02
Reel name =
```

On the other hand, when examining **the video resulting from stitching together the segments,** we find the following:

```
QuickTime Details:
Movie contains 1 video track(s), 1 audio track(s), 0 closed caption track(s), **and 0 timecode track(s).**

Video:
There are 19470 frames with a **duration of 41/1000ths.**

Video track 1:
Duration is **0:01:06:00**

Video data block #1:
Frame Size = 3840 x 2160
Compressor = 
**Quality = Normal (3.00)
Temporal = Normal (3.00)**
```

Comment: Does the desync show in other players, like VLC?

Comment: @Gyan Thanks for the great lead! No, VLC didn't seem to do anything strange. You got me thinking though, I looked at the clips in Premiere and found some interesting metadata. I'm going to update the original question to hopefully shed some more light on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Although I would've liked to have found a solution using only FFmpeg, I found that using Adobe Media Encoder's "Stitch Clips Together" functionality has given me an output that works without any apparent hiccups.

If I was going to solve it using FFmpeg, I would try and figure out why it changes the frame duration from 1/24 to 41/1000. Media Encoder's output preserves the frame duration of 1/24, and has no noticeable issues.